# converting date of format 23,59,59,997 to next day in java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an EndDate in millisecond and the way it is saved in DB is of format 2015-06-11 23,59,59,997. If i want to automatically add a startDate (endDate + 1) in millisecond, which is of format 2015-06-12 00,00,00,000. what is the best approach I can follow in javascript. Should i add the remaining milliseconds to the EndDate to calculate the StartDate ? If so how much millisecond is should add? or should I add 84600000ms with the EndDate and setHours(0,0,0,0).? Any help will be appretiated

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Speaking generally though, you can parse the date strings into a date object (or into moment.js), then do your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new date from the old date and add one to the day only.

```js
var mil=86400000;

var d = new Date(mil);
var newd=new Date(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()+1);
console.log(newd.toString());
```

Comment: thought the date stored in DB is in format '2015-06-11 23,59,59,999',  I will be getting as milllisecond in my application. So i want to convert the millisecond to next day.

Comment: @depperm doing `d=new Date(d.getTime()+1);` adds a millisecond. Also, remember that months are zero-indexed in JS (your code is returning july instead of june)

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
function roundDate (msUTC) {
  var proxyDate = new Date()
  proxyDate.setTime(msUTC)
  return (new Date(
    proxyDate.getUTCFullYear(),
    proxyDate.getUTCMonth(),
    (proxyDate.getUTCDate() + 1)
  ))
}


roundDate(235959997).toString()
```